# Migrating from Grails 1.x to 2.3.9 and fixing Spock tests to run in the process

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-controller

I have a question about Spock testing the list() method in a controller.  I am also migrating from Grails 1.x to Grails 2.3.9.  The question is how do I get the mock object I am creating visible to the controller so that when I call list() on it it sees the mock object.

Here is the code from the controller under test:

```
class XxCatalogFormController {
    def list() {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    [dpCatalogFormInstanceList: XxCatalogForm.list(), dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal: XxCatalogForm.count()]
}
```

Here is the Spock test I have:

```
@TestFor(XpCatalogFormController)
@Mock([XxCatalogForm, DpCatalog])
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class XpCatalogFormControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def 'list action: 1 dpCatalogForm'() {
    setup:
    mockDomain(XxCatalogForm, [dpCatalogFormInstance])
    mockDomain(DpCatalog, [catalog])
    params.max = 1
    when:

expect:
    controller.list() == [dpCatalogFormInstanceList: [dpCatalogFormInstance], dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal: 1]

    where:
    catalog = new DpCatalog(name: 'TestCatalog')
    dpCatalogFormInstance = new XxCatalogForm(url: 'catalog_testForm.gsp',
            catalog: catalog, confirmMessage: 'test', introBannerUrl: '/site/test.gsp',
            successUrl: 'test.gsp', name: 'test')

}
```

And here is the test result:

```
Condition not satisfied: controller.list() == [dpCatalogFormInstanceList: [dpCatalogFormInstance], dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal: 1] | | | | | | false com.kpi.dp.catalog.XxCatalogForm : (unsaved) | [dpCatalogFormInstanceList:[], dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal:0] com.kpi.dp.catalog.XxCatalogFormController@784f6502
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Condition not satisfied:

controller.list() == [dpCatalogFormInstanceList: [dpCatalogFormInstance], dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal: 1]
|          |      |                               |
|          |      false                                 com.kpi.dp.catalog.XxCatalogForm : (unsaved)
|          [dpCatalogFormInstanceList:[], dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal:0]
com.kpi.dp.catalog.XxCatalogFormController@784f6502

at com.kpi.dp.catalog.XxCatalogFormControllerSpec.list action: 1 dpCatalogForm(XxCatalogFormControllerSpec.groovy:64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to confirm which mixin is used in the test class, modifying the test class to use `@Mock` should work. Use `@Mock` instead of `mockDomain()`. Expecting the class to be under `test/unit`.

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(XxCatalogFormController)
@Mock([DpCatalog, XxCatalogForm])
class XxCatalogFormControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def 'list action: 1 dpCatalogForm'() {
        given:
        def catalog = new DpCatalog(name: 'TestCatalog')
        def dpCatalogFormInstance = new XxCatalogForm(
            url: 'catalog_testForm.gsp',
            catalog: catalog, 
            confirmMessage: 'test', 
            introBannerUrl: '/site/test.gsp',
            successUrl: 'test.gsp', name: 'test'
        )

        and:
        params.max = 1

        expect:
        controller.list() == [
            dpCatalogFormInstanceList: [dpCatalogFormInstance], 
            dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal: 1
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I added some more information about the test class.  The solution provided does not work.  I tried it and I get the same error.

Comment: Do not see `XxCatalogForm` in your update here `@Mock([DpCatalogForm, DpCatalog])`. `XxCatalogForm` is not mocked in your update as compared to the answer.

Comment: Note that the object referenced in the list() method of the controller is a class.

Comment: Share a sample app in github showcasing this issue in unit spec, I can look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer.  I appreciate it.  One quick question, how do I get the controller to recognized that there is a catalogFormInstance?  Not sure how to assign the instance to the model so the controller will see it.  In short the catalog.list() method is not seeing any instance but the right hand of the equality does see the created instance.

Comment: Take a look at this in the controller:  [dpCatalogFormInstanceList: XxCatalogForm.list(), dpCatalogFormInstanceTotal: XxCatalogForm.count()].  I am having problems populating that with test data.  I am using the Xx to hide the class name.

Comment: Take a look at this queston: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516062/upgrading-spock-unit-tests-from-grails-1-3-9-to-grails-2-3-9-but-edit-test-is