# Upgrading Spock unit tests from Grails 1.3.9 to Grails 2.3.9. But edit() test is failing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I am updating unit tests in a Grails project.  We were originally using version 1.3.9 and now we are updating to version 2.3.9.  I am using Spock.

I keep getting this error:

```
results:
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Condition not satisfied:
controller.edit() == [filterCategoryInstance: filterCategoryInstance]
|          |      |                             |
|          null   false                         John
com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.FilterCategoryController@20574000
```

Here is the controller code:

```
@Secured(["hasAnyRole('CM_ADMIN')"])
def edit() {
    def filterCategoryInstance = FilterCategory.get(params.id)
    if (!filterCategoryInstance) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'dpFilterCategory.label', default: 'FilterCategory'), params.id])}"
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    else {
        return [filterCategoryInstance: filterCategoryInstance]
    }
}
```

and here is the test code:

```
@Mock([FilterCategory, FilterCategoryTag])
@TestFor(FilterCategoryController)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class FilterCategoryControllerSpec extends ExtendedControllerSpec {

def 'edit action:  existing FilterCategory'() {
    setup:
        mockI18N(FilterCategoryController)
        params.id = filterCategoryInstance.id

   expect:
        controller.edit() == [filterCategoryInstance: filterCategoryInstance]


    where:
        tag = new FilterCategoryTag(name: 'tag1')
        filterCategoryInstance = new FilterCategory(name: "John", 
            submissionText:"John", sortOrder:0, 'filterCategoryTags': [tag])

}
```

And here is the ExtendedControllerSpec code.  I hope I have included enough code:

I have looked at the following web pages for guidance:

```
@Mixin(MetaClassMixin)
class ExtendedControllerSpec extends Specification {
def props

protected void setup() {
    //super.setup()

    props = new Properties()
    File file = new File("grails-app/i18n/messages.properties")
    if (file.exists()) {
        def stream = new FileInputStream(file)
        props.load stream
        stream.close()
    }

    mockI18N(controller)
}

def mockI18N = { controller ->
    controller.metaClass.message = { Map map ->
    if (!map.code)
        return ""
    if (map.args) {
        def formatter = new MessageFormat("")
        if (props.getProperty(map.code)) {
            formatter.applyPattern props.getProperty(map.code)
        }
        return formatter.format(map.args.toArray())
    } else {
        if (props && props.hasProperty(map.code)) {
            return props.getProperty(map.code)
        } else {
            return map.code
        }
    }
}

}

/**
 * add dynamic methods in test setup.
 */
protected void  addDynamicMethods() {
    registerMetaClass(String)
    String.metaClass.mixin StringUtils

}

protected GrailsUser mockGrailsUser() {
    return Mock(GrailsUser)
}

 ...

/**
 * must call AFTER mockDpSercurityService
 */

protected void setHasRoleTrue() {
    if (controller?.dpSecurityService?.metaClass) {
       controller.dpSecurityService.metaClass.hasRole = {return true}
    }

}
protected void setHasRoleFalse() {
    if (controller?.dpSecurityService?.metaClass) {
       controller.dpSecurityService.metaClass.hasRole = {return false}
    }

}


protected void mockUserService() {
    controller.dpUserService =  new MockFor(UserService)
}
```

}

- http://sanjaykanwar.blogspot.com/2012/07/grails-controller-test-with-spock.html
- http://naleid.com/blog/2012/05/01/upgrading-to-grails-2-unit-testing

Comment: after create filterCategoryInstance in where: , you need to save it into database. You can use this [build-test-plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) in order to quickly build your instance.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I appreciate it. Can you show me an example of using the plugin you mention? How do I save it? Again, thank you for the help.  I tried calling save() on the object but it did not work.

Comment: How does `ExtendedControllerSpec` look like?

Comment: I added come of the code from ExtendedControllerSpec.

Comment: @Dave, If the object doesn't work, you should check the errors like this `objInstance.errors.allErrors.each { println it}` to see what is missing. For the build-test-plugin, you should take a look at document, its easy to understand! (only need to call `DomainClass.build()`) (For example: `FilterCategoryTag.build(name: 'tag1')`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `if` branch gets executed in `edit()` instead of the `else` branch because `FilterCategory` does not get saved and therfore does not get a proper id.

Comment: You are right, the if branch is executed not the else branch.  How do I save the FilterCategory?  I tried calling save() but it did not work.

Comment: what did save() return? if true you may need to flush it. if false it is probably a validation error. Set failOnError to get a validation exception (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html)